# Is there a way to re-run called scripts and functions after minor edits from a Python app without having to close and restart the app?

Tags: python, pyqt5, editing

I recently got plunked into working on some existing code in Python.  The application uses PyQT5 to create a GUI which is then linked to various Python files containing scripts or functions.

My previous coding experience mostly revolved around Matlab apps in which edits can be made while the app is still running.  Any changes (that doesn't affect the structure of the GUI itself) in the underlying code will be reflected immediately the next time the application is asked to perform the relevant action.  I've gotten habituated to having this "iterative checking" ability.

I'd like to be able to do the same in Python.  As it is, (on a Windows 10 machine) I have to close the entire app and re-spawn it to test every change.  This is getting extremely time consuming especially for things that require trial and error like dialing in the visual appearances of the outputs.

Is there a way to have an instance of a PyQT5 app that will keep re-running an underlying script as it changes without having to re-spawn the whole thing?  If so, how do I go about setting that up?

Comment: Sounds like [Jupyter Notebook](https://jupyter.org/). There are other tools too.

Comment: Any advice as to where to start with Jupyter Notebook?  I'm not exactly sure how to map my issue into what I understand it to be.

Comment: Check [Jupyter Notebook Quickstart](https://jupyter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/content-quickstart.html).